# Does the DriverKit SDK support semaphores?

Tags: xcode, macos, driverkit

I can't find any functions like semaphore_create/semaphore_wait/semaphore_signal/semaphore_destroy in DriverKit headers.
it's not supported in Driverkit, Are there alternatives？

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores as in counting semaphores. Sadly there is nothing alike implemented.

Semaphores as in binary semaphores or mutex, there is something - `IOLock`. There is no documentation except in the header `IOLib.h`.

Using what you got, you could implement your own counting semaphore, since classes are supported in driverkit. Lock a counting member variable in class methods or something.